# Convert angularjs $http response to string/JSON

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Please be patient with me since I'm a beginner.

So I have this factory $http request to the server

**$http request**

```
factory.checkPollCodeIfAvail = function(x){
    code = x;
    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            'action' : 'checkPollCode',
            'pollCode' : code
        },
        url: 'http://localhost/poll/api.php',
        transformRequest:function(obj) {
            //transform header query into 'myVar1=var1Value&myVar2=var2Value'
            var str=[];
            for(var p in obj){
                str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]))
            }
            console.log(str.join("&"));
            return str.join("&"); 
        },
        headers:{'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }).then(function(response){
        var i = response.data.message.toString();
        console.log(i);
        return i;
    });
};
```

which would supposedly return `i` to my controller:

**Controller:**

```
pollCodeStatus = pollFactory.checkPollCodeIfAvail('qwe123');
console.log(pollCodeStatus.toString());
```

when I try to console.log the `i` in the `$http request` i will get a value string but when I tried console.log in the `controller` what I will get is an object `[object Object]`.

So can I convert an $http object to a string or even json data? if yes, how?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
factory.checkPollCodeIfAvail = function(x){
    code = x;
    return $http({
```

Your `checkPollCodeIfAvail` function is not returning `i`, it's returning a `Promise` that will eventually resolve to `i`. What does this mean? The HTTP call is *asynchronous*, so you need to *wait* until it finishes.

So in order to capture `i` in the controller, you need to do this:

```
pollFactory.checkPollCodeIfAvail('qwe123')
.then(function (pollCodeStatus) {
    console.log(pollCodeStatus)
})
```

Right now, as you've written it...

```
pollCodeStatus = pollFactory.checkPollCodeIfAvail('qwe123');
console.log(pollCodeStatus.toString());
```

...you are kind of expecting `checkPollCodeIfAvail` to run synchronously, which is not the case.

Comment: I see that's more understandable. Thank you  very much!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) return a promise object, that means your pollCodeStatus is a promise object.

The function you provide to `then` will be called if the promise object is resolved. This line `return i` is the return of the function you provide to `then`.

If you want to get `i`, you can use a global variable. Like the following:

```
var i 
factory.checkPollCodeIfAvail = function(x){
...
.then(function(response){
    i = response.data.message.toString();
});
};
console.log(i);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! you have almost the same answer as the one below. Thank youuu!!

Answer (score 0):

$http is for making an asynchronous calls and $http returns a promise object which needs to be resolved before accessing it. But in your code you have used it in a synchronous way .

You need to create a deferred object in the factory and return this deferred object.
So, here is the updated code :

> Inject ***$q*** into the factory first.

```
 factory.checkPollCodeIfAvail = function(x){
    code = x;
    var defered = $q.defer();
    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            'action' : 'checkPollCode',
            'pollCode' : code
        },
        url: 'http://localhost/poll/api.php',
        transformRequest:function(obj) {
            //transform header query into 'myVar1=var1Value&myVar2=var2Value'
            var str=[];
            for(var p in obj){
                str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]))
            }
            console.log(str.join("&"));
            return str.join("&"); 
        },
        headers:{'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }).then(function(response){
        defered.resolve(response.data.message.toString());
        var i = response.data.message.toString();
        console.log(i);
        return i;
    });
  return defered.promise;
};
```

And in your controller you will resolve like this:

```
pollFactory.checkPollCodeIfAvail('qwe123').then(function(resp){
console.log(resp);
});
```

This is the correct way of handling async calls from factory or service.
Hope this solves your problem. :)